# Ubuntu 20.04 screen keeps on refreshing automatically

Tags: 20.04, gnome, graphics, gnome-shell, systemd-journald

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and suddenly the whole screen turns purple, the same color on the login screen for 2 seconds, and refreshes automatically. There is no effect on the running tasks but it occurs after every 15 minutes since today.

[image: refreshing screen]

[image: logs after crash and reload]

Comment: try again by rebooting..!

Comment: Usually an extension crashes and gnome reloads. I had this when creating many files fast on the Desktop due to the "Desktop Icons" extension that is installed by default in Ubuntu. But might be another cause for you.