# Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS screen refreshs automatically

Tags: 20.04, gnome, updates, graphics

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and since I installed a new update, my desktop Icons and Background suddenly turn black, my cursor moves to the bottom right corner and then my screen turns purple (same as on the login screen) for a short amount of time.

In the System Monitor I realized that my cpu usage is really high when this happens. I already tried restarting and booting to recovery mode but I don't really know what I'm doing so I'm scared to touch anything.

I read that gnome extensions can cause this problems, but I've never installed any. I tried recording my screen to capture when it happens but the record stops when my screen turns black.

I think that I'm facing the same problem like [this guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331350/ubuntu-20-04-screen-keeps-on-refreshing-automatically) though it happens more often on my laptop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved It! I activated Wayland from the login screen and it seems to work now